# Use groovy expression for limited IP in mule

Tags: groovy, filter, mule

I created a proxy service with cxf in mule. My version of mule is 3.3.0 CE. Now, I want to put a restriction in my wsdl that created with proxy service.
My restriction shouldn't allow to per IP that they see my wsdl.
for this, I find Groovy expression and bellow code:

```
<expression-filter
        expression="#[groovy:'${allowed}'.contains(message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').substring(message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').indexOf('/')+1, message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').indexOf(':')))]"
        doc:name="Expression" />
```

I don't know Is good code Or no?
and I don't know where do I should define my valid Ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That approach is valid.
Only suggest I would do is to extract the IP parsing to a global function for reusability and better readability:

```
<configuration>
    <expression-language>
        <global-functions>
            def parseIp(fullIp) {
                return fullIp.substring(fullIp.indexOf('/') + 1, fullIp.indexOf(':'))
            }
        </global-functions>
    </expression-language>
</configuration>
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
<expression-filter expression="#['${allowed}'.contains(parseIp(message.inboundProperties['MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS']))]"
        doc:name="Expression" />
```

Comment: This is the best approach - if you're committed to IP-based filtering - except that the expression would better be wrapped with `#[ ]`. It works without because Mule 3 has a compatibility mode in place, but I strongly recommend using `#[ ]` to future-proof the config.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDossot and Seba for your reply. It works for me :)
Now I defined a global String named "allowed". Can I define global list instead of string? because I have list of valid IP for use my wsdl.

Comment: The code above uses `contains` so if your `allowed` string contains several IPs, say separated with comas, it'll work.

Comment: How and where do I set the values for the `${allowed}` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Restricting service based on IP address doesn't look a scalable approach.

What if you've more clients coming in or may be even for 1 client, request can be sent from different environments (prod, test, dev), then you'll have different IPs.

Client can also change their machine and IP won't remain same. You don't want to design a system in which changes on client end affects you and your solution should be scalable enough to accommodate more clients.

One solution is to look for `Securing your web service`. This blog post talks about it. http://blogs.mulesoft.org/securing-soap-web-services-using-ws-security/

Googling web service security with Mule will give your more results.

Comment: Thanks @Learner, I put username and password on my web service with Mule Spring Security Manager. I can't enable WS-Security.

Answer (score 0):

For Mule EE users, MuleSoft now offers an Enterprise Security module that includes an [IP filter](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Mule+Filter+Processor).