# How to set up MULE to accept incoming http calls only from "localhost"?

Tags: mule

i want my mule to accept calls from localhost only and not from any other source. i mean, someone should not do "publicIp/getCall", it should always be "localhost/getCall"( access to localhost only). How could we do that in mule_config file?

Comment: You could always extend the HTTP connector and check the source IP before deferring to the original implementation? Or just firewall port 80 on the Mule box...

Answer (score 2):

Mule changed this behavior ever since mule 3.4.0.

Now localhost binds only on the loopback address and not to all the network interfaces. If you want to listen only on the loopback you should use either localhost or the 127.0.0.1 ip address

Take a look at the [release notes](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+ESB+3.4.0+Release+Notes#MuleESB3.4.0ReleaseNotes-localhostBehavior) for more informations

While using older mule versions you can filter ip addresses that are not allowed. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599111/use-groovy-expression-for-limited-ip-in-mule) to understand how that can be achieved

Comment: It seems to me the OP is after the opposite: bind only to loopback, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. really appreciate it. i am new to using mule and wanted to know if there a way to change mule-config.xml so that SOME of the incoming calls cannot be made from outside that computer. our company is using mule 3.2.2, guess cannot change that to 3.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to map all of them you could use `0.0.0.0`. It will map localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the machine IP address, much better.